How to prepare outdoor aquarium before adding fishes?
I am trying to setup my first aquarium with 8 Chili Rasboras.
The tank is to be set outside in a large pot with a submerged lotus pot in the center. On the sides I have added sand (youtube said fishes love sand) and some rocks (for pouring water in). An article I found online suggested that floating plants are good biofilters so I will be adding water lettuce and salvinia natans (I have kept them in a separate pot for now).

Another youtube video suggests that I should introduce shrimps and let green algae grow as it somehow helps in biofiltration. So do I really need green algae and shrimps ?
If yes then which type of shrimp ?
Will they overpopulate ?
Does adding snails help in keeping shrimp population in check ?
Does shrimps or snails need rooted plants ?
Also, today I found something swimming in the water, is this good for the aquarium ?

Other parameters:

Tank water capacity is 24 litres (after adding sand and rocks).
Outside temperature in summer is
around 32 degree Celsius.
In Winter and monsoon its around 26 degree
Celsius
Water pH is 7 (as per drop test bottle, its neutral)
Water PPM is 20 (not sure if this is okay)


The little creatures on the leaves look like mosquito larvae. Fish love to eat them. Keep in mind that your water tank is black and might heat up much more than ambient temperature in the sun, which will decrease the amount of oxygen in the water and kill your fish.

@Elmy Will it workout if I add a solar powered filter ?

Be aware that an outdoor fishtank may become a buffet for local small predators.  Be prepared to restock it regularly, especially if there isn't enough space and depth for fish to retreat to.

@keshlam It is around 20cm deep. I hope the floating  plants and leaves will give enough spots to hide or I can introduce a hiding pot

As Elmy said, small amount of water and black container will make the water less breathable in summer for your fish. You can add something that bring bubbles into the water, like a fountain or a tube pushing air into the water (sorry, I do not know the english term for this). Filter would help, if you let the water "fall" into the water. Small container also tend to hold too much nutrition (easy to overfeed/have much waste from fish) and so make algae bloom. At night plants (incl. algae) take oxygene, so could drown fish at night. Swimming plant provide shade, good idea. Assume you need to try

@Allerleirauh Thanks for the suggestions, I am also reading into Walstad method. Also found that shrimps are good at keeping algae down and will self balance its population. I hope that will keep algae in control, however it might increase the bio-load.

Walstadt method sounds interesting. Please come back and answer your own question, when you have experience made. I found they expect to "plant heavy" but then you need to consider, that the plants "breath" oxygene at night. This will be risky in a small tank, which does not hold much oxygene, fish will be the first to die then. So a lot of plant means small amount of fish.
